# How to unsquash pushed commit to bitbucket

Tags: git, terminal, git-bash, git-reset, git-squash

I have squashed 7 commits (using `git rebase -i HEAD~7`) into a single commit and pushed the changes to bitbucket server. Now, I realized I need to push the 7 commits in original state.

I tried `git reflog` and `git reset --hard HEAD@{7}` But can only see one commit.

Answer (score 3):

In `git reflog`, there should be a line like,

```
8847515 HEAD@{7}: rebase -i (start): checkout HEAD~7
```

Now it may have become `HEAD@{8}` or `HEAD@{9}` in your repository. Find the stash entry right below this line, which is the original HEAD before the interactive rebase starts. It might be like `0874c8a HEAD@{10}: commit: foo bar`. Reset to this commit instead,

```
git reset 0874c8a --hard
```

Comment: Or `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD` if not much has been done between squashing and pushing.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way undo rebase:

```sh
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
# or
git checkout -b recoveredBranch ORIG_HEAD
```

This works only for last rebase.

Now `HEAD@{7}` will point to 7 states back of the head. It is hard to predict where it will point to. It depends what have you been doing. Every reset/checkout means that you have to increase this number.

As a last resort find last commit before rebase in a reflog and use its hash:

```sh
git checkout -b recoveredBranch a0a0ab0a
```